# How to set width for div regardles of child width

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make div's for my application behave in a way that they do not care about content size, but to use size given to them in percentage. I'm trying to solve this for quite some time now.

Here is a picture of my current layout:
[image]

Width of green elements that contain **R 9** and **R 8** are correct ones. The trouble is, if updated content contains number longer then one digit, it's width adjusts accordingly (as seen on **R 10** and **R 11**), but since my elements are rotated (transformed) I would like width of green element to stay unchanged. Element with **R 12** should be bigger then others, but same problem applies to it to.

So to sum up, **I would like that width of red element does not change width of green element**. Or, if that is not possible, some other workaround with the same visual effect would do, but the former is preferred.

Here is index.html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        /*other imports*/
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vertical.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MyController">
        <div class="bg-primary element" ng-repeat="element in elemnts" 
            ng-class="{width13: $first, width9: !$first}">
            <div class="element_container">
                <p class="transform270deg" ng-class="{font20: $first}">
                    <small ng-if="$first">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play font10"></i>
                    </small>
                    {{element.label}} {{element.number}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is vertical.css:

```
.transform270deg {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.element {
  display: table;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 10vmin;
}

.element p {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.element_container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: green;
}

.width13 {
  width: 13%;
}

.width9 {
  width: 9%;
}

.font10 {
  font-size: 10vmin;
}

.font20 {
  font-size: 20vmin;
}
```

Comment: It's always easier for others if you post your output html (without angular in it) and maybe create a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: You can try one thing, you can put position:relative to element_container and position:absolute to  your p tags. But in this case you have to set height width of containers.